# Issue with adding new items to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON to store user data. Through out the code I use an object called plotStatus, which when a user first visits the page is set as equal to initalPlotStatus. When I add items to initalPlotStatus, it is set as undefined in plotStatus.

Say I make a JSON save like this

```
let initalPlotStatus = {
   peas: "empty",
   corn: "empty",
   strawberries: "empty",
   eggplants: "empty",
}
```

Then later I add new variables like this

```
let initalPlotStatus = {
   peas: "empty",
   corn: "empty",
   strawberries: "empty",
   eggplants: "empty",
   pumpkins: "empty",
   cabbages: "empty",
}
```

But the JSON save is missing those values, which when called return undefined, which requires the save to be wiped to solve.

Values are saved like this

```
var saveLoop = window.setInterval(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("plotStatus", JSON.stringify(plotStatus, replacer));
}, 1000)

let savegame = {
    plotStatus: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("plotStatus")),
}
plotStatus = savegame.plotStatus;

if (savegame !== null) {
    savegame.plotStatus = plotStatus;
}

function restart() {
    plotStatus = initalPlotStatus;
    // Save
    localStorage.setItem("plotStatus", JSON.stringify(plotStatus, replacer));
     // Reload
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Those are objects. JSON is a text format used to transmit or store them. Anyway, how are you adding items, and how are you saving / restoring the status?

Comment: Still not sure what the problem is but `plotStatus = initalPlotStatus;` doesn't create a copy. After that line, doing something like `plotStatus.a = "b"` will also make the same change to `initialPlotStatus` because they're both the same object now. Also, the six lines in the middle of that code can most likely be replaced with `plotStatus =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("plotStatus"))` (savegame !== null will always be the case)

Comment: I am changing the values of `initialPlotStatus`, which is not used anywhere in the code after the first time the page is visited.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it know. You basically want to merge the saved values with the new initial values. First load plotStatus, then call `plotStatus = Object.assign({...initalPlotStatus}, plotStatus);`